# Rails routing using devise and subdomain constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to route root to devise sign in path under a `subdomain` constraint.

My `config/routes.rb` look something like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw 
  constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
    devise_scope :admin do
      root to: 'devise/sessions#new'

      # here I override devise routes
    end
  end

  root to: 'pages#homepage'

  # rest of the routes  
end
```

I am getting the error `Could not find devise mapping for path "/".`

Any suggestions as to how I route to root path in a subdomain with devise scope?

Thanks

Comment: Does it works like that: 
`root to: 'devise/sessions#new', constraints: { subdomain: 'admin' }`

Comment: Thanks for following up. I would still need to put it inside the `devise_scope` block thereby overriding default devise routes. To do that I have put it inside a `constraint` block. Somehow, I'm still not able to access `devise` controllers from there.

Answer (score 1):

To add an authentication constrain to a route use the devise `authenticated` method:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw 
  constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
    authenticated :admin do
      # the root page for authenticated users
      root 'admin#dashboard', as: :authenticated_root
    end
    root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  end

  # this is for no subdomain
  root to: 'pages#homepage'
end
```

Comment: `devise_scope` is really just a devise version of `scope` that mounts routes in the devise path. `devise_scope :users` would mount paths in `/users`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We can only route to devise controllers from inside a `devise_scope`. I tried using `unauthenticated` to route to root but it's still showing the same error message. Is there a way I can `devise_scope` routes and override defaults, while also specifying `root to: 'devise/sessions#new'`?